# How to send bulk sms in twilio api without for loop

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I'm trying to send bulk sms through twilio Api. Is there any method to pass the array of all phone numbers in a single API request.

Comment: By this we cannot send msgs with a single API call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Yes there is now! It's known as the [passthrough API](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/bulk-sms-with-one-api-request.html) (as it allows you to pass through many different messaging systems and send bulk messages. It's part of the [Notify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify) and you can use it to send bulk SMS messages. You need to set up a messaging service and a notify service in your console, then you can use the following code:

```
<?php
// NOTE: This example uses the next generation Twilio helper library - for more
// information on how to download and install this version, visit
// https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from https://www.twilio.com/console
$accountSid = "your_account_sid";
$authToken = "your_auth_token";

// your notify service sid
$serviceSid = "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

// Initialize the client
$client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

// Create a notification
$notification = $client
    ->notify->services($serviceSid)
    ->notifications->create([
        "toBinding" => [
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+15555555555"}',
            '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+12345678912"}'
        ],
        "body" => "Hello Bob"
    ]);
```

Checkout [the documentation on sending multiple messages with the Notify passthrough API for all the details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications#sending-to-bindings-in-the-notification-request).

Comment: How can you use this method (single API call with multiple recipients as an array identified by the `toBinding` parameter) and be able to get back the Twilio unique identifier for each sent message so it can later be linked back to my database entry for the sms sent via a twilio callback update?

Comment: @philnash can you please review the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65789251/not-recieving-sms-using-twilio-notify-service-no-debug-error-in-console

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else had troubles with preparing the toBinding parameter from a PHP array() as I had, here is an example for that:

```
<?php
require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$accountSid = "your_account_sid";
$authToken = "your_auth_token";
$serviceSid = "ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$client = new Client($accountSid, $authToken);

$recipients = array($num1, $num2, ...); // Your array of phone numbers

$binding = array();
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { 
    $binding[] = '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+1'.$recipient.'"}'; // +1 is used for US country code. You should use your own country code.
}

$notification = $client
->notify->services($service_sid)
->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => $binding,
    "body" => $text
]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to configure your twilio number properly for notification. Then your to use below code to send bulk SMS.

```
$message = 'Any text message';
$to = array();
foreach ($users as $user) { 
    $to[] = '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"'.$user->phone_number.'"}';
}

$sid    = 'TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID';
$token  = 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN';
$services_id = 'TWILIO_SERVICE_ID';
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);


$notification = $twilio
->notify->services($services_id)
->notifications->create([
    "toBinding" => $to,
    "body" => $message
]);
```