# Not recieving sms using twilio notify service, no debug error in console?

Tags: twilio, sms, twilio-api, notify, twilio-php

I am trying to send bulk SMS using Twilio notify API. I had looked at the documentation, and other StackOverflow resources but did not find the issue yet. What I am doing is:

```
$sid = "AC1e590cbb8eee064c3c71axxxxxxxxxxx";
$token = "94c2dc3e2e407c4ebd28cxxxxxxxxxxx";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);
$serviceSid = "IS32913ae9b083b809b1c06xxxxxxxxxxx";

$recipients = array();
foreach($phone_nos as $phone_no) {
   array_push($recipients, $phone_no['phone_no']);
}

//recipients array print value is 
//Array
//(
    //[0] => +923105653361
    //[1] => +923491457062
//)

$binding = array();
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { 
   $binding[] = '{"binding_type":"sms", "address":"'.$recipient.'"}';
}

//binding array is print value is
//Array
//(
    //[0] => {"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+923105653361"}
    //[1] => {"binding_type":"sms", "address":"+923491457062"}
//)

$service = $twilio->notify->v1->services->create();
$notification = $twilio->notify->services($serviceSid)
   ->notifications->create([
   "toBinding" => $binding,
   "body" => 'Test message 5 notify'
]);

echo $notification->body;
echo '<pre>';print_r($notification->sid);exit;
```

The notify console is showing the messages are sent with no error.

[image]

Comment: @philnash can you please review the question.

Comment: I don’t see an error here. What is the problem?

Comment: not receiving the SMS.

Comment: Are you able to send those messages using the regular messaging API?

Comment: Yes, I tested that, which is working properly, reviewed the SMS on the same numbers.

Comment: Have you connected a messaging service with a phone number in the number pool to your Notify service?

Comment: No, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you haven’t connected a messaging service and a phone number to your Notify service. Follow the [instructions in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/sms#messagingservice) to set that up, then try sending the messages again.

Comment: While I was adding I did not see the USE CASE option in my notify service menu. Where I can setup the number also, I didn't find the option anywhere.

Comment: Please check the image here: https://imgur.com/a/Elk8nPp

Comment: Go to “Sender Pool” in the left hand menu from that screen shot.

Comment: One last thing I want to log the response by setting the ` // "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST","status_callback" => AURL .'Sms/bulk_sms_status_callback'` but it generates the error message.

Comment: can you please look into the new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65879032/how-to-answer-incoming-call-in-browser-using-javascript-and-php

Comment: can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971266/while-adding-alphanumeric-sender-id-i-always-got-error-in-php