# While adding Alphanumeric Sender ID I always got error in php

Tags: twilio, sms, notify, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

I had purchased a USA number and I am trying to send a programable message to Hong Kong. While I send with a simple Twilio number it works fine and message recieved.

But when I try to add alphanumeric Sender ID it always show error message. The error message is: `Message: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: The 'From' number infoSMS is not a valid phone number, shortcode, or alphanumeric sender ID.`

What I had tried is

```
public function send_sms(){
    $msg_to = $_REQUEST['msg_to'];
    $msg_body = $_REQUEST['msg_body'];

    $twilio = new Client("ACba7f3a6866a23aed021056d3ceaexxxx", "4d7e47e92a8351b7365ed1e3e83dxxxx");
    $message = $twilio->messages->create(
        $msg_to, // to
        [
            "body" => $msg_body,
            "from" => "infoSMS";
        ]
    );

    if($message->sid) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('ok_message', '- SMS successfully sent!');
        redirect(AURL . 'Sms/sent_sms_list');
    }else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', '- Error in sending sms please try again!');
        redirect(SURL . 'Sms/create_sms');
    }       
}
```

I had read the documentation: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#use-an-alphanumeric-sender-id

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a free trial Twilio account? Because alphanumeric sender ID is only available for upgraded accounts.

Comment: I am using an upgraded account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This was a bit hard to track down, but it turns out that there are a few generic alphanumeric sender IDs that may cause delivery failures. I tried to send an SMS using "infoSMS" as the sender ID and was unable to do so as well.

On some of our [SMS guideline pages](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/dm/sms), there is this note about alphanumeric sender IDs:

> Generic Alpha Sender IDs like *InfoSMS, INFO, Verify, Notify* etc should be avoided as they will result in SMS failures

I recommend you try using a different alphanumeric sender ID that more closely represents your business or service.

Comment: Yes, I contacted support they told me the same, and the issue was resolved.